# Hover over div content to reveal new div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

```
<center>
    <div class="trivlimp">
        <center><div class="lyrics"><!-- |field_1| --></div></center>
    </div>

    <div class="imp">
        <div class="trgls"><!-- |points| --> Gallons</div><br>
        <div class="trals"><!== |field_2| --></div><br>
        <div class="trpc"><!-- |posts| --> posts</div><br>
        <div class="trttr"><!-- |field_3| --></div><br>
    </div>
</center>
```

I'd like to be able to hover over the div "trivlimp" to show the div "imp" right on top of "trivlimp"; hiding the first div underneath the div "imp". I tried doing this by :hover but completely failed and only ended up making it more frustrating for myself. I'm not against using Jquery, but I'd like to do this completely by css; but if it is easier using jquery I'll use it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Could you specify in more detail which element could be hovered and which parts of the document should be visible or invisible, both in the 'normal' state and in the hover state?

Comment: In the normal state, I'd like for the div "imp" to be hidden, then shown when the content of the div "trivlimp" is hovered on, with the div content of "imp" hiding the content of the div "trivlimp". Kinda like when you hover an image, showing a new image, but this time with content?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Thrw2/3/

html code

```
<center>
<div class="trivlimp">
    <center><div class="lyrics"> |field_1| </div></center>
</div>

<div class="imp">
    <div class="trgls"> |points|  Gallons</div><br>
    <div class="trals">|field_2| </div><br>
    <div class="trpc"> |posts|  posts</div><br>
    <div class="trttr">|field_3|</div><br>
</div>
```

css code

```
.trivlimp {     background-color:#FF0000;
    width: 260px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute; }
.imp {     width: 260px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#676767;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; }

.lyrics {
    margin-top: 50%;
    background-color: #CC0066;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 130px
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.trgls {
    width: 190px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 35px;
    background-color:#6666FF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.trals {
    width: 170px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 35px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.trpc {
    width: 150px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 35px;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.trttr {
    width: 130px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 35px;
    background-color: #009900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
$('.trivlimp').hover(function() {
    $('.imp').show();
},
function() {
    $('.imp').hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question, but you could use the following:

```
.imp {
    display: none;
}

.trivlimp:hover + .imp {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery to work with the hover states. I'm somewhat not following the question as well. So I popped your code into JSFiddle and brewed up what I thought was along the lines of what you're looking for. I used jQuery's mouseover/mouseout:

```
$('.trivlimp').mouseover(function() {
    $('.imp').show();
});

$('.trivlimp').mouseout(function() {
    $('.imp').hide();
});
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/arsCr/

Comment: It appears to work on that site, but when I put in my own css and widths; it doesn't work, the div "trivlimp" when hovered doesn't show the div "imp". (this is on my site) Would it help if I supplied my css?

Comment: Create a JSFiddle with your HTML and CSS (without the jQuery addition). Post back and I will take a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Thrw2/ I think I did that right, I put in all the css used for this, and the html.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/PWtTw/
html:

```
<div class="trivlimp">
</div>

<div class="imp">
</div>​
```

css:

```
.trivlimp{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

.imp{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    display: none;
}
```

​
jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.trivlimp').hover(function() {
        $('.imp').show();
    }, function() {
        $('.imp').hide();
    });
});​
```